# How to calibrate multiple touchscreen connected on 2 different graphic cards?

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen, xinput, monitor-calibration

I have a sytem define as in the attached piture:

[image: Touchscreen Architecture]

So 2 graphic cards:

1. Screen 0 = 1 Touchscreen + Normal Screen
2. Screen 1 = 4 Touchscreens.

I have tried to calibrate with `xinput-calibrator` but I failed.
Doesn't matter if I launch with the screen 0 or screen 1 I get each time the mis-click problem after the first or second clicks.

I have tried also with the `xinput` method to calibrate the Transformation matrix:

```
xinput set-prop "Device Name" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" c0 0 c1 0 c2 c3 0 0 1
```

I have got some results but the problem is that it seems the 2 screens are not really separated. For instance if I calibrate the screen 1 (just taking the TS10 into account), when I touch the screen the mouse move on the normal screen even on another graphic card.

I don't know how to manage this problem... and I did not yet find another post with this kind of configuration with 2 graphic cards.

Many thanks in advance for any idea I could try.